# use malloc leads to error

Tags: c++, malloc

I am trying to translate some code from objective c to unmanaged c++
I have this operation

```cpp
Buffer* ir =malloc( sizeof( Buffer ) );
```

error: expression must have pointer-to type?
the same error goes into this code

```cpp
ir->buffer = malloc( bufferSize );
```

Could you please provide me correct use of `malloc` in this unmanaged c++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc()` returns a `void *` which might be leading to this issue.  You can cast the return:

```
Buffer *ir = (Buffer *)malloc(sizeof(Buffer));
```

or, if you're using C++, you should use `new` instead:

```
Buffer *ir = new Buffer;
```

(If you do, don't forget to change the `free()` to `delete` though).

Comment: Thank you! Is it correct in the second case write something like ir->buffer = new bufferSize ?

Comment: No.  You don't specify the type of `ir->buffer` but I suspect it's `unsigned char`, so you would need `ir->buffer = new unsigned char [bufferSize]` to allocate it (and `delete [] ir->buffer` to free it).  However this should be done in the `Buffer` class itself, not "outside" really.  Sounds like you need to implement a `Buffer` class to do this right.

Comment: Blind replacement of `malloc()` with `new` is not a good idea - `malloc()` returns null on failure and code checking for that null will no longer work when you replace it with `new`.

Comment: @sharptooth Agreed; the default behaviour for `new` is to throw an exception upon failure, so any `NULL` tests will have to be replaced with `try-catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Buffer *ir = (Buffer*) malloc (sizeof(Buffer));
```

However, the better C++ way is to have a constructor in the `Buffer` class and then use something like

```
Buffer *ir = new Buffer;
```

or perhaps (if the constructor take some arguments)

```
Buffer *ir = new Buffer(args);
```

Comment: Basile, thank for your post but trojanfoe gived the same answer first.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you use new instead of malloc in c++. Malloc is ENTIRELY unaware of constructors and it's more often than not considered a good practise to use ' new ' (and therefore it's twin ' delete ').

Do make sure not to use malloc with delete or new with free though, i've seen what it can do and let me tell you it's not pleasant.

Comment: Thank you, Scarlet! your answer is usefull for me